# Ajax loading div is not displaying

Tags: jquery, ajax, document-ready

I have the following codes and I don't understand why the loading gif is not displaying. The `loadingDiv` is initially hidden in my stylesheet. Should the ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions sit inside or outside of dom ready?

```
<div id="loadingDiv">
        <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="ajaxLoad"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loadingDiv').hide().ajaxStart( function() {
             $(this).show();  // show Loading Div
         }).ajaxStop(function(){
                $(this).hide(); // hide loading div
           });
        $("#ajaxLoad").load("engine.php");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is chaining to the wrong element which does not have a ajax process (the loading image) and change to  **`.ajaxComplete()`** instead try below one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loadingDiv').hide()
            $("#ajaxLoad").ajaxStart( function() {
                 $('#loadingDiv').show();  // show Loading Div
            }).ajaxComplete(function(){ // <--------------try with .ajaxComplete
                  $('#loadingDiv').hide(); // hide loading div
            });
            $("#ajaxLoad").load("engine.php");
         });
</script>
```

---

#### Update

**From the docs:**

> As of jQuery 1.8, the ".ajaxStart()" method should only be attached to "document".
>
> As of jQuery 1.8, the ".ajaxStop()" method should only be attached to "document".
>
> As of jQuery 1.8, the ".ajaxComplete()" method should only be attached to "document".

So if you are using 1.8+ then try the below one:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#loadingDiv').hide();

            $(document).ajaxStart( function() {
                 $('#loadingDiv').show();  // show Loading Div
            }).ajaxComplete(function(){ // <--------------try with .ajaxComplete
                  $('#loadingDiv').hide(); // hide loading div
            });
            $("#ajaxLoad").load("engine.php");
         });
</script>
```

Comment: you are invoking `ajaxStart` on `#ajaxLoad` element, so `$(this)` wouldn't point to `#loadingDiv`.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't show the loading gif to begin with, same issue it seems.

Comment: @BenPaton what version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: @NOX May be you saw that code which i copy/pasted and have not changed the `$(this)` to `$('#loadingDiv')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code that will work here you are missing something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loadingDiv').hide()
            $("#ajaxLoad").ajaxStart( function() {
                 $('#loadingDiv').show();  // show Loading Div
            }).ajaxComplete(function(){ 
                  $('#loadingDiv').hide(); // hide loading div
             }).load("engine.php");
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making the AJAX call inside the div called "**ajaxLoad**", but you are setting the ajaxStart/ajaxStop events inside the "**loadingDiv**" div. These AJAX events will never fire that way. You'll either need to attach the AJAX event handlers to a parent div from **loadingDiv**, so that they'll bubble up, or make the calls in the same div as the one where the ajaxStart/ajaxStop events are set up.

Check these pages for more information:

- http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/
- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: This theory sounds right but I can't get the code to work. I have a parent div of pagewrapper, should I be attaching the ajax events on this?